# Why is Woocommerce shop not working on mobile?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've set up a WooCommerce shop and it seems to work properly on desktop:
https://www.barefoottravelling.de/prints/

If I check the same shop/page on my mobile phone I can't see any products unfortunately. I've searched for advice a couple of days but couldn't figure out the issue.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you add the code of the relevant part of the site?

Answer (score 0):

In your css file, you have this property defined as:

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
 .woocommerce-posts-wrapper .woocommerce-shorting-wrapper p {
  display:none;
 }
```

etc etc.

That means, if your width screen is less than 480px, the items will disappear. You can just remove it.
This is how it looks for me after removing it (You see that the items appeared).

[image]